# linux small business finance software

Tags: linux, software-rec, finance

I'd like a financial management package that runs on linux.

A web-based system would be ok, but it must be installable on my server.

Is there anything out there?

(Must be linux, but I'm willing to pay for it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend reading [this](http://freshmeat.net/articles/financial-software-for-linux) article.  It has a list of financial management software, from software to manage your personal finances, to financial software that a Fortune 500 company could use.

Answer (score 1):

here are some Linux alternatives listed

[Financial Management Software for Linux](http://adventuresinswitching.blogspot.com/2008/01/financial-management-software-for-linux.html)

Comment: It's amazing what you can find when you Google things isn't it? :)

Comment: Thanks. +1 because it is useful to know alternatives for personal finance, but I am looking for business finance.